# Is there a tool for summarizing what all commands do?

Tags: command-line, command

So I understand that there are `man` pages for getting the documentation when the internet is unavailable, or when you need advanced uses, but what if I'm offline and I don't even know what tool I need for the job? Is there a command that lets me see each program/command and a short description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the bash(1) built-in `compgen`

- `compgen -c` will list all the commands you could run.
- `compgen -a` will list all the aliases you could run.
- `compgen -b` will list all the built-ins you could run.
- `compgen -k` will list all the keywords you could run.
- `compgen -A function` will list all the functions you could run.
- `compgen -A function -abck` will list all the above in one go.

The above command lists all the available commands for an user based on his privileges set. I disabled the network and tested the above command and it works even when disabled. However, for short description, as far as I can tell, once you get an command, you can view the man page.

Some other commands that can be used to view the description about a command are,

```
apropos
whatis
less
groff
```

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/949006/1742825

Comment: Of course, that wouldn't necessarily tell you if running those commands will do anything *useful*. Taking your disabled networks example, I suppose `ping` would still be listed as executable, but it wouldn't do you much good. Also, isn't this based on the user's current `$PATH`, meaning that if a command is not within one of the directories named as the search path it will never show up?

Comment: `apropos -s1` seems like a better answer, because it includes a one-line description of what each command does. What this answer does contribute is a list of aliases, functions, etc, but with no explanation of them it's of limited use, IMO.

Answer (score 9):

In general: No, some programs come without documentation.

However, `apropos` might be just what you need.

For example `apropos ssh` will list the man pages related to ssh, in my case:

```
authorized_keys (5)  - OpenSSH SSH daemon
git-shell (1)        - Restricted login shell for Git-only SSH access
rlogin (1)           - OpenSSH SSH client (remote login program)
rsh (1)              - OpenSSH SSH client (remote login program)
slogin (1)           - OpenSSH SSH client (remote login program)
ssh (1)              - OpenSSH SSH client (remote login program)
ssh-add (1)          - adds private key identities to the authentication agent
ssh-agent (1)        - authentication agent
ssh-argv0 (1)        - replaces the old ssh command-name as hostname     handling
ssh-copy-id (1)      - use locally available keys to authorise logins on a     remote machine
ssh-keygen (1)       - authentication key generation, management and conversion
ssh-keyscan (1)      - gather ssh public keys
ssh-keysign (8)      - ssh helper program for host-based authentication
ssh-pkcs11-helper (8) - ssh-agent helper program for PKCS#11 support
ssh_config (5)       - OpenSSH SSH client configuration files
sshd (8)             - OpenSSH SSH daemon
sshd_config (5)      - OpenSSH SSH daemon configuration file
XAllocClassHint (3)  - allocate class hints structure and set or read a window's WM_CLASS property
XClassHint (3)       - allocate class hints structure and set or read a window's WM_CLASS property
XGetClassHint (3)    - allocate class hints structure and set or read a window's WM_CLASS property
XSetClassHint (3)    - allocate class hints structure and set or read a window's WM_CLASS property
XtIsShell (3)        - obtain and verify a widget's class
```

You can see some pages appear more than once, the reason being that `rsh` `slogin` and `ssh` have the same man page.
Also there (as usual) false positives.

Comment: I guess although not **exactly** what I was looking for, definitely a very helpful and similar tool. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe add to your answer `apropos -s1`, which will pull all commands from `man` section 1, and only those commands, which seems to be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

You can read short description of many commands using `whatis`:

```
$ whatis pwd
pwd (1p)             - return working directory name
pwd (1)              - print name of current/working directory
pwd (n)              - Return the absolute path of the current working directory
```

And you can ask for several commands:

```
$ whatis pwd ls ps
pwd (1p)             - return working directory name
pwd (1)              - print name of current/working directory
pwd (n)              - Return the absolute path of the current working directory
ls (1p)              - list directory contents
ls (1)               - list directory contents
ps (1)               - report a snapshot of the current processes.
ps (1p)              - report process status
```

Therefore, you can try to generate list of descriptions of all commands by combining `whatis` with `compgen`:

```
$ whatis $(compgen -c)
```

Comment: If it generates some garbage on STDERR you can use ` whatis $(compgen -c) 2>/dev/null ` to clean it.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` you can start with a simple `help` invocation from the prompt to have a *built-in* command list and after refine with `help commandname`, `man commandname` and `man -k commandname` (the last to extend the research to the related ones).

You can find useful to read even `info coreutils` and `info`.(not only in `bash`)

At the end of the `man` pages (and `info` too) for each command there is a list of other related commands after the title `SEE ALSO`. A good starting point to expand your research.