# Using a glob pattern as an argument to "which"

Tags: wildcards, which

Is it possible to use the `which` command on a glob pattern to return multiple results?

For example, I want to know the full path of all my `latex` commands. I can try:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ which latex
/usr/bin/latex
```

or:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ which pdflatex 
/usr/bin/pdflatex
```

or:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ which xelatex 
/usr/bin/xelatex
```

but I cannot use:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ which *latex
```

which returns nothing.

Any suggestions on how to use a glob pattern with the `which` command?

Comment: although it is a broadstroke, in this type of situation I use locate <partofname> , this of course does not show you where an executable is but where that file is. locate expects updatedb to be run regularly to stay up to date.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh` (note that `which` is only built in `tcsh` or `zsh`, in other shells it can give random results, use `type` in Bourne like shells):

```
$ which -m '*latex'
/usr/bin/arlatex
/usr/bin/dvilualatex
/usr/bin/fig4latex
/usr/bin/latex
/usr/bin/lualatex
/usr/bin/pdflatex
/usr/bin/pod2latex
/usr/bin/pslatex
```

Or (if you only want to consider executables and not functions, aliases...):

```
$ ls -ld $^path/*latex(-*DN)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    53 Apr  8 03:14 /usr/bin/arlatex -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/bundledoc/arlatex*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     6 Apr  8 03:51 /usr/bin/dvilualatex -> luatex*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    55 Apr  8 03:51 /usr/bin/fig4latex -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/fig4latex/fig4latex*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     6 Apr  8 03:51 /usr/bin/latex -> pdftex*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     6 Apr  8 03:51 /usr/bin/lualatex -> luatex*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     6 Apr  8 03:51 /usr/bin/pdflatex -> pdftex*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10340 May 20  2013 /usr/bin/pod2latex*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    54 Apr  8 03:14 /usr/bin/pslatex -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/pslatex.sh*
```

With other Bourne-like shells, you could do:

```
searchPATH() (
  pattern=$1
  IFS=:; set -f; set -- $PATH
  set +f; IFS=
  for i do
    for j in "$i"/$pattern; do
      [ -x "$j" ] && printf '%s\n' "$j"
    done
  done
)
```

And then:

```
$ searchPATH '*latex'
/usr/bin/arlatex
/usr/bin/dvilualatex
/usr/bin/fig4latex
/usr/bin/latex
/usr/bin/lualatex
/usr/bin/pdflatex
/usr/bin/pod2latex
/usr/bin/pslatex
```

That should work more the most common values of `$PATH`. It will omit the entries in the current directory if `$PATH` ends in `:` (like `/bin:/usr/bin:`)

Answer (score 0):

With *Bash*, using the [`compgen`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/130969/44370) and `type` *builtins*, assuming no newline character in the command names:

```
IFS=$'\n'; set -f; type -p -- $(compgen -c | grep 'latex$')
```

Comment: Would be more something like `IFS=$'\n'; set -f; type -p -- $(compgen -c | grep 'latex$')` (and still assuming no newline character in command names).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It was also quite wasteful that I sent all the `compgen` output to `type`. Thanks for the input!